# how to load a application bundle in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, bundle

I want to load an application bundle file in iPhone OS?what is the procedure to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, using public APIs that are acceptable on the App Store. You can reference other applications that support URIs though. For more information, read [Apple Approved iPhone Inter-process Communication](http://www.mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/) at Mobile Orchard.